# Android change imageview size dynamically by image size

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Hi I have a ImageView which displays image from url. The images are of different sizes. They may be either square shaped or portrait shaped or landscape shaped. I need to set the image view size accordingly with out stretching or cropping.

Say if the image size is 512x512 then the ImageView should be in square shape and aligned center of the screen.

If the image size is something like 1024x800 then the ImageView size should be in horizontal rectangle shape and aligned center of the screen.

In all case the width should match parent but height should adjust accordingly. How can I do this?

Below in my xml code.

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:maxHeight="400dp"
>         android:maxWidth="300dp"
>         android:layout_margin="10dp"
>         app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="vertical">
>             <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:scrollbars="none">
>                 <ImageView
>                     android:id="@+id/image"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>                     android:scaleType="fitXY"
>                     android:minWidth="260dp"
>                     tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
>             </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
>
>             <View
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="1dp"
>                 android:background="@color/grey_light" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/title"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="35dp"
>                 android:layout_gravity="right"
>                 android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_small_low"
>                 android:background="@drawable/transparent_bg"
>                 android:textColor="@color/orange" />
>         </LinearLayout>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Comment: remove android:scaleType="fitXY" from xml
& calculate your image height by aspect ratio like (deviceheight * imagewidth)/devicewidth

Comment: Removing it creates blank space in the ImageView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set width of imageView to match_parent in the xml and calculate height of the image at runtime to maintain the aspect ratio using below code:

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int newWidth = size.x;

//Get actual width and height of image
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();

// Calculate the ratio between height and width of Original Image
float ratio = (float) height / (float) width;
float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int newHeight = (int) (width * ratio)/scale;
```

Pass this newHeight and newWidth to resize your image by calling .resize function of your image processing library.

Answer (score 1):

Heard of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library? It not just center crop the image but it manages the complexity of caching for you.

How to setup? Add this dependency in your Gradle and sync.

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

How to use the library? Simple, you just need to call a singleton code.

```
ImageView imageView  = ....
Picasso.with(contextHere())
       .load("http://example.com/myimage.jpg)
       .fit()
       .centerCrop()
       .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

change `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to  `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

And set `ImageView` width according Screen width , means you should calculate width for `ImageView` by 60 percentage of screen width or something like that and use  `android:scaleType="centerInside"` may calculate height itself without changing Image aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Jsut put wrap_content it will automatically take a size.

        android:layout_height="wrap_cont`enter code here`ent"
        />

Comment: Please read the complete question. He wants width of the image to be match_parent always.

Answer (score 0):

For the dynamic ImageView need to set Height = WrapeContent and ScaleType =  "FitXY",

Its Work perfectly for me.
Check below code

```
              <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/ivNews"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/temp_image"
                />
```